# Понятие такое-то. Нужны ли кавычки после слова "понятие"?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Национальный институт охраны труда ввел понятие "концентрации, непосредственно опасные для жизни и здоровья".

Нужны ли кавычки в предложении?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из словаря:

**ПОНЯТИЕ**, 1. Мысль, отражающая существенные свойства и необходимые признаки предмета или явления. П. времени. П. качества. П. треугольника. 
(Здесь используется **форма Р.п., кавычек нет**).

В то же время **кавычки после слова понятия ставятся часто**, если далее следует **словосочетание,** например: *На этот раз они предлагают конкретизировать понятие "наружная реклама"*; *Понятие "серебряный век" он стал употреблять в числе первых, одновременно с Маковским и Бердяевым*.

**В приведенном примере кавычки желательны,** так как речь идет **о мн. числе** существительного ―  "**концентрации**, непосредственно опасные для жизни и здоровья". Здесь речь идет, вероятно,  о концентрациях различных вредных веществ, причем для каждого из них указывается своя количественная характеристика.

Похожий материал: [Концентрация вредных веществ, мгновенно-опасная для жизни или здоровья | Викитека](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2,_%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше: *Национальный институт охраны труда ввел понятие концентрации, непосредственно опасной для жизни и здоровья*. И затруднений с кавычками нет.